# How to get crispy vegetables chips/fries without frying?

Tags: vegetables, oven, chips, fryer

Specifically for sweet potatoes, I'd like to get crispy fries via the oven rather than a fryer. Here are some pointers I've read in other recipes:

- Cuts must be as equal as possible to ensure even cooking
- Wash off excess starch / let raw fries sit in a bowl of cold water to remove excess starch

Also, I just purchased a mandolin so I'd like to hear any techniques/advice on getting crispy vegetable chips.

Thanks in advance for the help.

**-- Edit 1 --**

Unfortunately, my results have been disappointing and inconsistent. With the thinnest setting on my mandolin, I sliced up some sweet potatoes and beets. I've tried some of the tips mention on the [Chowhound](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/378235). I've tried a variety of heat settings but I haven't found the sweet spot of heat and time just yet. With those two variables I really don't want to perform 10-30 trial runs but it's looking like I need to if I want to determine the best configuration. I'm going to try some other tips and report back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of recipes for oven-"fried" sweet potato chips (crisps) and fries (chips) and I'll let you search that part. I've noticed a wide variation in recommended oven temperatures, from as low as 350 to as high as 450. Though I've never had great success with crispiness, my overall best results were with a temp of 425.

Crispiness with sweet potatoes is notoriously difficult due to the high water and sugar content (which will caramelize and make them appear and to some extent taste burnt, usually long before they crisp up). There's some discussion of this on [Chowhound](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/378235).

Key points seem to be:

- remove as much surface moisture as possible prior to cooking
- avoid overcrowding the pans, especially when cooking thicker cuts
- use a convection oven if possible

If you have success please report back and tell us what worked!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will be making some chips within the week so I will post my findings.

Comment: I would also add getting the oil good and hot in the oven beforehand - put it in at least 20 minutes before adding the potatoes (be careful of hot oil splattering). As for drying, I usually par boil my potatoes for 5 minutes before cooking, allowing plenty of time for them to steam dry before they go in the oven (half an hour at least).

Answer (score 1):

I was dubious at first about making chips in the microwave, but after a terrible fail using the oven I thought I'd give it a try.

- Rinse a nice sized Russet potato to remove any debris.  I left the skin on.
- Cut in half and then use a mandoline on ultrathin setting to make 1.5mm slices.  *For **bigger** chips from smaller potatoes, cut the potato on an angle when cutting in half.  This will result in more oblong chips...great for dipping!*
- Gently spray a 12 inch plate (not the potatoes) with cooking spray.  I used Pam.
- Gently rinse the slices and pat dry first to remove some starch for slightly crispier chips.
- Place non-overlapping slices around plate starting with the outside, leaving the center area empty (my microwave cooked the center way too fast).
- In my microwave a Whirlpool Gold carousel, it took about 6 minutes for the first batch.  Add more time if they are not starting to brown or stop early if any are getting too dark.
- Careful with the plate when they are done.  It will be very hot.
- I leave plate in microwave, sliding chips off into a bowl with a fork or knife.
- I then place a new batch of slices on plate while it is still in microwave and repeat the process.  The cooking time seems to be shorter for successive batches, so adjust time accordingly.
- Watch them pretty carefully until you get the hang of it.

I leave plate in microwave

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried this, but there's a recipe for  microwave potato chips here:
http://www.thekitchn.com/recipe-recommendation-diy-pota-64078